# How to disable lockscreen response to EmptySpaceClick in Android12

Tags: android

In Android 12, the interface for entering a password on lockscreen will respond to EmptySpaceClick and re-enter the lockscreen state.Users will think this is a bug.
So how to disable response to EmptySpaceClick?

Steps to Reproduce :

1. Go to Settings -> Security.
2. Click on “Screen Lock” option.
3. Choose a Password as a screen lock.
4. Set a Password.
5. Wait for device to get Locked.
6. Swipe up on Lock Screen.
7. Click on Text box or empty space on Login screen while typing.
8. Lock screen is appeared again.

Click on text box or empty area on other versions of Android does not re-enter the lockscreen state, and still requires the user to enter a password.